# Word lists for different languages?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, language

I find word lists fun (and hence useful) when learning languages. On linux these are provided by `apt` and friends ( e.g. `/usr/share/dict/words` -- [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/wngerman) is the debian package for such a list in German). This consists of an alphabetic list of a lot of words.

You can do things like find words that sound like another word - to make learning vocabulary fun and have it stick in your head more. You can find compound words that use a word. You can explore the spelling and orthography in a language. I mostly do this using
[grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) and [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

This approach of language learning is consittent with [Data-driven learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_learning) - a rather niche area that and it is my belief is better suited to particular personalities and people with particular experiences. More complete solutions that use this approach include things like [learning with texts](https://learning-with-texts.sourceforge.io/), [lingvist](https://lingvist.com/) and [language reactor](https://www.languagereactor.com/) but these can be opinionated and I don't think they provide the ability to search for words that sound or are spelled alike.

Are there open-source or commercial software that provide various different languages' word lists (text files) on macOS?

Comment: You might need to define exactly what you mean by 'word list'.

Comment: What is it exactly that you do on linux with these "lists" that you want to do on your Mac?

Comment: @Tetujin the one's in /usr/share/dict/words? I've added a link to an exampl package in debian.

Comment: I ended up using this: https://gist.github.com/MarvinJWendt/2f4f4154b8ae218600eb091a5706b5f4

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to Apple products nor is it known what the actual problem is to be solved.   The user stated in comments that they downloaded a word list that was nothing more than a .txt file.

Comment: Regarding "related to an apple product" - in linux this is a feature of the OS and linked up with spell checkers - so "provide me with word lists" might be something that you would expect an OS to do or you could view it as an incidental side effect of how spellchecking (probably a core OS feature).  It's also worth noting that the *english* word list is present on mac... at least on my box `/usr/share/dict/words`` but I have found a work around.

Comment: If this gets closed again, please refer to https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for guidance about making your requirements explicit and enumerated. Good research so far, though and hopefully my answer spurs others to contribute / edit.

Comment: @AttRigh, the issue with the question is it starts of with a statement about how word lists can be "fun."  Nowhere do you make the distinction of it being needed as a *custom dictionary* for the system to utilize.  That, unfortunately  makes it a [potential dupe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+dictionary). When asking questions, it's important to be clear and specific - remember, we can't know what you want unless you tell us.

Comment: @Allan If you look at the question you might note that I want a word list. A word list is what I want. That is why I started the question is "word list", also why I ask for a word list at the end.  I say exactly what I want to do with it (grep it) and give an exact corresponding example from another operating system. To stop joking... I think there's XY-problem analysis where people desire higher-level description - this can be tiresome if you know what you want: I suppose it would be I want to do [data-driven language learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_learning) and can code

Comment: Okay I've added a higher level description. I'm a little concerned that this turns into a discussion on "you should use anki for spaced repetition" when what I want is a word list rather than to completely replan my approach. I guess it's possible that someone could refer me to a complete solution that does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The homebrew package manager has a dict client / package / database of many words (mostly english iirc).

- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dict

I haven't looked at the source code, but the [language tool](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/languagetool) might be worth an install once you get the above set up on your mac as it's just one more line to download and install it.